# Angular momentum in pieces of a fracturing object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, geometry

I have a physics problem that's a bit beyond my knowledge to solve and I haven't been able to find a clear answer for that I trust. Let's say I have a 2d asteroid in the shape of a convex polygon of uniform density in space. It is rotating uniformly around its center of mass when another arbitrary event causes it to split unevenly into two new uniform, concave polygons without otherwise altering the underlying momentum. The two pieces, to my understanding, fly away from one another according to their new centers of mass in relation to the asteroid's total CoM on breakage. That part is fairly simple.

What I'm confused about is how I should go about figuring out the angular velocity these two pieces will have upon separation. Clearly the angular velocity will be very different depending how big each piece is. My hunch would be some kind of integration on the momentum of each point within the two pieces, but I imagine there's a more elegant solution.

Edit:
Adding more info, I'll just list out all the detail that seems relevant:

An asteroid is an object comprised of n segments, where each segment is a triangle. The asteroid has a density value that is uniform. The asteroid has a hull polygon, a collection of counterclockwise ordered points that enclose it in the form of a polygon (which can be convex, but is not necessarily convex).

At any point, one segment at a time may be removed from the asteroid, with the constraint that the removed segment must be a "hull segment", i.e. a segment with at least one edge that is not shared by another segment. When this happens, a breakage occurs if the updated hull polygon would intersect. This breakage results in the two pieces flying apart from one another.

If the solution is just to check the relative velocities of each segment, then that works great. However, I'm not sure how I would transform the individual segment velocities into an angular momentum, so I could use advice on that.

Comment: I think you need. more specifics for this to be answerable, but in general you would use conservation of momentum, angular momentum around any point, and kinetic + rotational kinetic energy conservation (if elastic) to constrain the final speeds

Comment: I added an edit to give more information, thank you

Comment: Try calculating in 2 dimensions the angular velocity of an arbitrary point on a rotating body about another arbitrary point on the rotating body (not just the center). The results may surprise you, and I think they'll answer your question.